# EFT operators to Feynman Diagrams

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, effective-field-theory

I have this paper [arXiv:1410.4193](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.4193) which contains a complete list of pre-EWSB dimension-7 EFT operators, and I have taken them and 'converted' them to post-EWSB operators. As an example, from the $\psi^4H$ operator
$$
\mathcal{O}_{\overline{L}uddH} = (\overline{L}_id_R)(u_R^TCd_R)\tilde{H}^i
$$
we get
$$
\frac{v}{2}(\overline{\nu}_Ld_R)(u_R^TCd_R).
$$
All the fields are Dirac spinors, except for $L$ and $H$ which are $SU(2)$ doublets. $\ell_R$ ($\ell_L$) should be understood as $P_R\psi_\ell$ ($P_L\psi_\ell$). C is the charge conjugation operator (such that $Cd_R = d_R^c$ is an anti-quark, right?),the overline means Dirac adjoint, and tilde means $SU(2)$ conjugate $(\tilde{H}^i = \epsilon_{ij}(H^j)^*)$. I'm working in the Weyl basis.

Anyways, I am trying to extract the Feynman diagram for the vertex (vertices?) that this operator produces. I don't care about coefficients right now, just the diagram. I thought Dirac adjoint corresponded to an outgoing state, so that the diagram would be
$$
dd^cu \longrightarrow \nu.
$$
This doesn't make sense, since the baryon number on the LHS is then $B = \frac{1}{3}(2 - 1) = \frac{1}{3}$. Additionally, all dim-7 operators should either be $(\Delta L = 2, \Delta B = 0)$ or $(\Delta L = -1, \Delta B = 1)$. Had the diagram been
$$
ddu \longrightarrow \nu^c,
$$
it would have made sense. What am I doing wrong?